# Finding length of all arrays multidimensional array, Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-length

I would like to use a multidimensional array to store a grid of data. However, I have not found a simple way to find the length of the **2nd** part of the array. For example:

```
boolean[][] array = new boolean[3][5];
System.out.println(array.length);
```

will only output **3**.

Is there another simple command to find the length of the second array? (i.e. output 5 in the same manner)

Comment: `System.out.println(array[0].length);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `array[0].length`, this will give the dimension you're looking for (since your array is not jagged).

Comment: +1 for hinting that not all multi-dimensional arrays are necessarily square.

Answer (score 7):

```
boolean[][] array = new boolean[3][5];
```

Creates an array of three arrays (5 `boolean`s each). In Java multidimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays:

```
array.length
```

gives you the length of the "outer" array (3 in this case).

```
array[0].length
```

gives you the length of the first "inner" array (5 in this case).

```
array[1].length
```

and

```
array[2].length
```

will also give you 5, since in this case, all three "inner" arrays, `array[0]`, `array[1]`, and `array[2]` are all the same length.

Answer (score 1):

array[0].length would give you 5

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = array.length;

if (a > 0) {
  int b = array[a - 1].length;
}
```

should do the trick, in your case a would be 3, b 5

Comment: This will cause an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: Except that this will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since `a` is the length of `array`. You probably just meant to use `0`

Comment: @Brian fixxed it - it's too late for me -.-

Comment: Well, I +1'd because of your bounds check with `a > 0`, but Idk who downvoted, sorry.

Comment: @Brian I am not even sure if it is necessary, because new boolean[0][5] wouldn't work anyway, right?

Comment: @user28061 Sure it would (and does). You can make 0-length arrays, and that's exactly what `new boolean[0][5]` does.

Comment: Why use `array[a - 1].length` when you could use `array[0].length`?

Comment: @A. R. S. If `new boolean[0]` works, `array [0]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Yes I understand, but you could just do `if (array.length > 0) { int b = array[0].length; }` instead of defining that `a` variable right?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the length of the inner array in a 3 dimensional array

e.g.

```
int ia[][][] = new ia [4][3][5];
System.out.print(ia.length);//prints 4
System.out.print(ia[0].length);//prints 3
System.out.print(ia[0].[0].length); // prints 5 the inner          array in a three  D array
```

By induction: For a four dimensional array it's:

```
ia[0].[0].[0].length
```

......