# How to count array elements inside an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array as follows in nodejs

```
 var dataary=[];
    dataary=[ [ 'reg_no', 'slno', 'name', 'email', 'rollno' ],
    [ 'int', 'int', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'int' ],
    [ '100', '11', '255', '255', '100' ] ]
```

I need the count of array elements.As i do dataary.length it will return 3. But i need the count as 5 (count of elements inside array).How can i get the count of elements.  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: use `dataary[0].length`.

Comment: Note: It just so happens that the length is 5 for all of the arrays in `dataary`, but it could just as easily be that they each had different lengths.

Comment: `But i need the count of elements inside each array` - loop through the main array and extract the length of each sub array? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502843/finding-length-of-all-arrays-multidimensional-array-java

Comment: `But i need the count as 5 ` You need to get answer as 5 or 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through loop and get length of each individual `array` .The **forEach()** method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```js
var dataary=[];
    dataary=[ [ 'reg_no', 'slno', 'name', 'email', 'rollno' ],
    [ 'int', 'int', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'int' ],
    [ '100', '11', '255', '255', '100' ] ,
    [ '1', '2', '3' ]]
    dataary.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.length);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

With map you can get all lengths in one array and then you can sum them or do whatever you want to do.

```
var allLengths = dataary.map(element => {
   return element.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way...

```
dataary.reduce((count, innerArray) => count + innerArray.length, 0);
```